# How do I Export group pricing?

Tags: importexport

I know how to go about exporting all of my products into a CSV but I noticed that it only has MSRP, Price and Special price but does not have Group Prices that I have gone in and manually set. Where do I go to export this price for individiual products? Is there a way to do this? and perhaps import the group pricing later on?

Answer (score 1):

System => Export => Advanced Pricing